# Consecutive days calendar in profile page is not correctly displayed on Firefox only

Tags: bug, profile-page, consecutive-days, calendar

I noticed for 2 or 3 weeks, the calendar of the profile page (when I click on the number of consecutive days I visited SO) is not correctly display on Firefox only. I don't reproduce the problem on Google Chrome for example.
I'm using `Firefox 26.0`, with no theme and no plugin, except HTTPS-Everywhere and All-in-One Sidebar, but I don't think they can have any connection with this.

Here is what I have on my Firefox :

[image]

I have reproduced this problem with my personal computer, and the the office's one (only with FF).
I found on meta but didn't found any similar topic... Am I the only one to have this problem or is it a known bug ?

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 26.0.

Comment: `https` has been known to cause a lot of problems lately. Try disabling the extension and see what happens.

Comment: @Antony OMG you're right, it works without HTTPS-Everywhere... I never see any problem like this with this plugin elsewhere, is there any explanation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed HTTPS-Everywere to test it. When enabling it, I got the same as on your image. The solution is to disable it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, with this plugin disabled, everything is OK... I've never see this before, is there any explanation ?

Comment: @AlexB: When clicking on the "X consecutive" link, the page sends an AJAX request. One of the parts of the response is probably not SSL encrypted.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about this problem. I'm absolutely not skilled in security, but it could potentially be a weakness an attacker can exploit... SO developpers could take a look to this problem I think...
Anyway, thank you for your answer !